# How can I extract raw bytes of DOS stub using python's pefile library?

Tags: python, portable-executable

I want to extract raw bytes of DOS stub using `pefile` library. Does `pefile` have a feature for this?

If it doesn't then I have to do it manually. I guess DOS stub always starts at offset 0x40 but where does it end?

It can't be assumed that DOS stub continues until reaching "PE" signature pointed to by `e_lfanew`. This is because a Rich header may be present between DOS stub and "PE" signature. `pefile` provides `parse_rich_header` method but that apparently doesn't return the offset of the Rich header. It only returns the content of the Rich header.

Besides programs can determine their own DOS stub. So the size of DOS stub can vary. Is there a maximum for size of DOS stub?

Values of `e_cp` and `e_cblp` fields of DOS header cannot be trusted. They can be easily forged ([See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196444/what-is-e-cblp-and-e-cp-in-dos-header).) I have files that have wrong values for these fields. 2, 3, and 20050 are three most common values for `e_cp` in my files. Clearly 1 should be the most common value for `e_cp`.

Comment: One ugly way to do it is 1) If there is no Rich header (`pe.parse_rich_header() == None`) then return `pe.header[0x40:pe.DOS_HEADER.e_lfanew]` 2) If there is a Rich header (`pe.parse_rich_header() != None`) then search for subsequence of bytes given by `pe.parse_rich_header()["raw_data"]` inside `pe.header` to find the offset of the Rich header and return `pe.header[0x40:offset_to_Rich_header]`. The way this method finds the offset of Rich_header is suboptimal. This method considers anything after offset 0x40 up to Rich header, or if that doesn't exist, up to PE signature as part of DOS stub.